# How to keep smooth lines when drawing out animated bezier curves in html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, curve, bezier

I finally found out how to animate drawing a bezier curve. I've seen other solutions that use quadratic curves to do it, but I needed 4 points for what I was doing, and b-spline was too difficult finding random plots, plus it's just how I want to do it; with Bezier Cuves.

My issue is I can't find a good, fast speed without seeing the dots or lines. I've gotta be missing something. Could someone point out my error or a more efficient way to get this going smoothly at any time/speed? I need it to be steady and go faster than the example below, but if I do anymore the gaps get larger and larger...

fiddle with code: https://jsfiddle.net/qzsy8aL7/

```
//B(t) = (1 - t)^3P0 + 3t(1 - t)^2 P1 + 3t^2(1 - t)P2 + t^3P3
function animatedBSpline(context, points, t) {
    // Draw curve segment
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(
    Math.pow(1 - t, 3) * points[0].x +
    3 * t * Math.pow(1 - t, 2) * points[1].x +
    3 * Math.pow(t, 2) * (1 - t) * points[2].x +
    Math.pow(t, 3) * points[3].x,

    Math.pow(1 - t, 3) * points[0].y +
    3 * t * Math.pow(1 - t, 2) * points[1].y +
    3 * Math.pow(t, 2) * (1 - t) * points[2].y +
    Math.pow(t, 3) * points[3].y
  );

  // Draw spline segemnts
  context.lineTo(
    Math.pow((1 - t) + 0.001, 3) * points[0].x +
    3 * (t + 0.001) * Math.pow((1 - t) + 0.001, 2) * points[1].x +
    3 * Math.pow(t + 0.001, 2) * (1 - (t + 0.001)) * points[2].x +
    Math.pow(t + 0.001, 3) * points[3].x,

    Math.pow((1 - t) + 0.001, 3) * points[0].y +
    3 * (t + 0.001) * Math.pow((1 - t) + 0.001, 2) * points[1].y +
    3 * Math.pow(t + 0.001, 2) * (1 - (t + 0.001)) * points[2].y +
    Math.pow(t + 0.001, 3) * points[3].y
  );

  //33d4ff
  context.strokeStyle="#35bb23";
  context.lineJoin="round";
  context.lineWidth=2;
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.stroke();
  context.fill();

  // Keep going until t = 1
  if (t < 1) requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    animatedBSpline(context, points, t + 0.01);
  });
  else
    context.closePath();
}
```

If any more information is needed please let me know. I've been at this all day.

To add:
If I just outright draw it with these plots, and not animate it being done, it looks fine, obviously, but just wanted to point that out. Its something with the way I'm animating it I just don't know.

Comment: Well I noticed that at each segment you call `context.beginPath()` and `context.moveTo(...)` which will cause the segments to become disjoint. You should only call those two methods at the beginning of a curve, not at every point.

Comment: where else would I put it? If I put it anywhere else testing it either fills black with multiple little lines (I think) or doesn't do anything.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qzsy8aL7/1/ I'm not sure if this is what you're going for but I made the line continuous and removed that nasty `eval`, turning `points` into an array instead.

Comment: Minus all the black. I was just trying to get lines and that's it.

Comment: Alright, I'll post an answer with the updated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the full updated code with animation of green bezier curve:

```js
(function() {
  var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

  $(function() {
    var canvas = $('#drawings')[0];
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var lineLength = 0;
    var lineLengthMax = 7;
    var timer;

    // Define points
    var points = [[{
      x: 600,
      y: 200
    }, {
      x: 550,
      y: 100
    }, {
      x: 350,
      y: 100
    }, {
      x: 300,
      y: 250
    }],
    [{
      x: 350,
      y: 250
    }, {
      x: 75,
      y: 225
    }, {
      x: 30,
      y: 400
    }, {
      x: 120,
      y: 450
    }],
    [{
      x: 200,
      y: 450
    }, {
      x: 5,
      y: 380
    }, {
      x: 25,
      y: 750
    }, {
      x: 175,
      y: 610
    }],
    [{
      x: 200,
      y: 520
    }, {
      x: 150,
      y: 560
    }, {
      x: 175,
      y: 750
    }, {
      x: 325,
      y: 605
    }],
    [{
      x: 400,
      y: 395
    }, {
      x: 275,
      y: 450
    }, {
      x: 250,
      y: 750
    }, {
      x: 565,
      y: 655
    }],
    [{
      x: 515,
      y: 540
    }, {
      x: 500,
      y: 695
    }, {
      x: 660,
      y: 675
    }, {
      x: 675,
      y: 560
    }],
    [{
      x: 600,
      y: 400
    }, {
      x: 790,
      y: 315
    }, {
      x: 1005,
      y: 500
    }, {
      x: 675,
      y: 585
    }],
    [{
      x: 500,
      y: 250
    }, {
      x: 700,
      y: 100
    }, {
      x: 775,
      y: 350
    }, {
      x: 700,
      y: 380
    }]];

    //33d4ff
    context.strokeStyle="#35bb23";
    context.lineJoin="round";
    context.lineWidth=2;

    doLineDraw();
    //animatedBSpline(context, points, 0);

    function doLineDraw() {
      if (lineLength <= lineLengthMax) {
        clearTimeout(timer);

        // Kick things off at t = 0
        context.beginPath();
        animatedBSpline(context, points[lineLength], 0);
        //animatedBSpline(context, eval('points'+(lineLength)), 0);

        lineLength++;
        if (lineLength <= lineLengthMax)
          timer = setTimeout(doLineDraw, 2000);
      }
    }

    //B(t) = (1 - t)^3P0 + 3t(1 - t)^2 P1 + 3t^2(1 - t)P2 + t^3P3
    function animatedBSpline(context, points, t) {
      // Draw curve segment
      if (t == 0)
        context.moveTo(
          Math.pow(1 - t, 3) * points[0].x +
          3 * t * Math.pow(1 - t, 2) * points[1].x +
          3 * Math.pow(t, 2) * (1 - t) * points[2].x +
          Math.pow(t, 3) * points[3].x,

          Math.pow(1 - t, 3) * points[0].y +
          3 * t * Math.pow(1 - t, 2) * points[1].y +
          3 * Math.pow(t, 2) * (1 - t) * points[2].y +
          Math.pow(t, 3) * points[3].y
        );
      
      // Draw spline segemnts
      context.lineTo(
        Math.pow((1 - t) + 0.001, 3) * points[0].x +
        3 * (t + 0.001) * Math.pow((1 - t) + 0.001, 2) * points[1].x +
        3 * Math.pow(t + 0.001, 2) * (1 - (t + 0.001)) * points[2].x +
        Math.pow(t + 0.001, 3) * points[3].x,

        Math.pow((1 - t) + 0.001, 3) * points[0].y +
        3 * (t + 0.001) * Math.pow((1 - t) + 0.001, 2) * points[1].y +
        3 * Math.pow(t + 0.001, 2) * (1 - (t + 0.001)) * points[2].y +
        Math.pow(t + 0.001, 3) * points[3].y
      );
   
      
      //context.fillStyle = "black";
      context.stroke();
      //context.fill();
   
      // Keep going until t = 1
      if (t < 1) requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        animatedBSpline(context, points, t + 0.01);
      });
    }
  });
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <article>
    <canvas id="drawings" width="1000" height="1000" />
  </article>
</section>
```

A couple key points, some of which were tangential to the question.

- Avoid using `eval` for referencing variable names which have numbers post-fixed. Just use an array instead.
- The reason you were drawing points instead of lines was because you called `context.beginPath()` and `context.moveTo()` before every new vertex, which causes `context.stroke()` and `context.fill()` to "forget" the previous instructions.

I moved the `context.beginPath()` outside of `animatedBSpline()` and specified `context.moveTo()` to run at `t==0` within that function, that way there are no disjointed points. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, and for explaining. There wasn't a ton on this with bezier curves and had to dig like crazy.

Comment: protip: just use straight up multiplication rather than `Math.pow`, since we're dealing with lower powers. `let t2 = t*t, mt = 1-t, mt2 = mt*mt, t3 = t2*t, mt3=mt*mt2`, and now you're not constantly invoking the function call overhead, either. Same for that step size: make it a var so you can easily vary it instead of having `0.001` hardcoded everywhere (for small curves, 0.001 is probably an order of magnitude more than you actually need)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks. I literally copied and pasted the math, all I was addressing here was the question that was asked (and the `eval`)

Comment: yup, so: never too late to edit an answer to be even better =) (SO answers are not just for the person asking, but also every future visitor who finds this answer because they had the same original question. The better the answer, the better off everyone is)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I understand, but this isn't code review. I answered a question.

Comment: While it's true that It's not code review, and just answering a question is of course fine, improving that question so that even more people benefit from it is absolutely within the scope *and purpose* of Stackoverflow.